# Send FIle over ftp Android

Tags: android, ftp

I've this code to send file over ftp

```
 FTPClient con = null;

    try
    {
        con = new FTPClient();
        con.connect("192.168.1.100");

        if (con.login("gustavo", "gustavo"))
        {
            con.enterLocalPassiveMode(); // important!
            con.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
            String data = "/data/data/com.prosec/files/WhiteList.txt";
            System.out.println("chguei aqui");

            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File(data));
            boolean result = con.storeFile("/data/data/com.prosec/files/WhiteList.txt", in);
            in.close();
            if (result) Log.v("upload result", "succeeded");
            con.logout();
            con.disconnect();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("erro web");
    }
```

In my ftp server, ai received this message

```
(000011)28/10/2015 12:50:16 - gustavo (192.168.1.101)> STOR /data/data/com.prosec/files/WhiteList.txt
(000011)28/10/2015 12:50:16 - gustavo (192.168.1.101)> 550 Filename invali
```

but this file exist

prosec is my package name, so, i should has acess to /data/data/prosec

how can I to send a file in this directory?

Answer (score 0):

Use `ContextWrapper.getFilesDir()` to get your directory instead of hard coding it. This may solve your issue? Let me know.

Comment: like this? String data = (ContextWrapper.getFilesDir()+ "WhiteList.txt");

Comment: `String data = ContextWrapper.getFilesDir() + WhiteList.txt;` no need for the extra brackets. - Make sure your file name is correct.